# Undefined control sequence. \end{tableau}

Tags: forest, trees, logic

[image]

Why the error. TeXStudio.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{ot-tableau}
%\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{tableau}
    {
        line no sep = 1.5cm,
        just sep = 1.5cm, % Set separation of justification
        for tree = {s sep'=10mm},
        close with = \absurd
    }
    [((P \land Q) \lif R), just={Premiss}
    [\neg(P \lif (Q \lif R)), just={Negated conclusion}
    [P, just={From (2)}
    [\neg(Q \lif R), just={From (2)}
    [Q, just={From (4)}
    [\neg R, s sep=30mm, just={From (4)} %Note "s sep" to
    %spread fork below
    [\neg(P \land Q), just={Alternatives from (1)}
    [\neg P, close, just={Alternatives from (7)}
    ]
    [\neg Q, close
    ]
    ]
    [R, close]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the exact text of the error message.

Comment: You need to define `\lif`. EDIT: and `\absurd`.

Comment: The exact text of the error message is the title of the question

Comment: No it isn't. The crucial part of the error message i.e. the name of the control sequence which is undefined is missing. Besides, it should be in the question and it should include the line number. It isn't `\end{tableau}` which is undefined. You've only reported a fragment of the message and that fragment doesn't include the key information provided.

Comment: Thanks @cfr! 
I just copied the error out of TeXStudio using its copy function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define (or avoid) `\lif` and `\absurd`. In the following, I define `\lif` and avoid `\absurd`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{ot-tableau}
%\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\newcommand*{\lif}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{tableau}
    {
        line no sep = 1.5cm,
        just sep = 1.5cm, % Set separation of justification
        for tree = {s sep'=10mm},
%         close with = \absurd
    }
    [((P \land Q) \lif R), just={Premiss}
    [\neg(P \lif (Q \lif R)), just={Negated conclusion}
    [P, just={From (2)}
    [\neg(Q \lif R), just={From (2)}
    [Q, just={From (4)}
    [\neg R, s sep=30mm, just={From (4)} %Note "s sep" to
    %spread fork below
    [\neg(P \land Q), just={Alternatives from (1)}
    [\neg P, close, just={Alternatives from (7)}
    ]
    [\neg Q, close
    ]
    ]
    [R, close]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: tableau]

Comment: How can you define \absurd?